# Особенности работы пакета APEX_JSON в oracle при использовании n-пользователями одновременно

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Для формирования *JSON* в БД ORACLE использую пакет *APEX_JSON*

Пример:

```
declare
  l_cnt_cycle number;
begin
  apex_json.initialize_clob_output;

  apex_json.open_object();
  apex_json.write('id', 1);
  apex_json.write('name', 'test_name');
  apex_json.write('manager', '', p_write_null => true); 

  apex_json.open_array('test_arrays'); 
  for l_cnt_cycle in 0 .. 3
  loop
    apex_json.open_object();
    apex_json.write('id', l_cnt_cycle);
    apex_json.write('name', 'test_arr' || ' ' || l_cnt_cycle);
    apex_json.close_object();
  end loop;

  apex_json.close_array(); 
  apex_json.close_object(); 
  dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_clob_output);
  apex_json.free_output;
end;
```

В доке указано, что данный пакет использует *HTP buffer*, но я не нашел описания следующих моментов:

1. Как поведёт себя этот буфер, когда n пользователей будут одновременно использовать функцию формирования JSON, в которой задействован данный пакет
2. Не попадут ли результаты пользователя №1 к пользователю №2
3. Будет ли происходить его автоочистка, если не будет вызвана команда *.free_output*

Comment: Разные сессии внутри СУБД работают изолированно. Чтобы они друг другу мешали, это надо специально постараться.

Comment: У нас используется механизм липких сессий и была ситуация, когда при выборке из буфера пользователю n1 попала информация n2. 
Может ли этот нюанс как-то отразиться на использовании пакета? Или команда free_output решает данную проблему?